# golang ssh dial timeout

Tags: go, ssh

What is the best way to create DialTimeout on ssh connection? For example, this code always returns "Ping deadline exceed":

```
func (t *Tunnel) ping(sshConn *ssh.Client, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
    var (
        conn net.Conn
        err  error
        done chan int
    )
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(getSeconds(10))
        err = errors.New("Ping deadline exceed")
        log.Printf("%v\nStatus: bad %s -> %s", err, t.serverAddr, addr)
        t.writeStatus(bad)
        done <- 1
        close(done)
    }()
    go func() {
        conn, err = sshConn.Dial("tcp", addr)
        if err != nil {
            t.writeStatus(bad)
            log.Printf("%v\nStatus: bad %s -> %s", err, t.serverAddr, addr)
        }
        done <- 1
        close(done)
    }()
    <-done
    return conn, err
}
```

PS Timeout in ssh.ClientConfig is set to 5 seconds

Comment: I've set timeout in ssh.ClientConfig, but i still have infinite delay when ssh server is closed. However, I've found a mistake, `done chan int` needs to be created though `make(chan int)`

Comment: Sorry, I initially misunderstood your question. There is no way to supply a timeout for an ssh `direct-tcpip` command, but the remote host should be able to timeout eventually, though probably not in under 10 seconds (depends on the remote hosts kernel TCP settings)

Answer (score 3):

> It's been two years but, may someone need the solution. So here it is.

In ssh.Dial, you can give configuration via **ssh.ClientConfig**,

```
config := &ssh.ClientConfig { Timeout: time.Minute }
client, _ := ssh.Dial("tcp", t.ServerAddr, config)
```

You can find more in [here](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#ClientConfig):

> // A Timeout of zero means no timeout. 
>   Timeout time.Duration

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using sshConn.Dial take a look at:

```
func DialTimeout(network, address string, timeout time.Duration) (Conn, error)
```

From the [connection docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn):

> DialTimeout acts like Dial but takes a timeout. The timeout includes
>   name resolution, if required.

Comment: direct-tcpip does not support deadlines. https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/golang/crypto/-/blob/ssh/tcpip.go#L453.